# The different possible ways the phrase " most definitely " is correctly used

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrase-usage

What do Native Am/Brit.Eng speakers really mean when they  say "it's most definitely ( that ) ... " or reply with "most definitely." ?

Is there only one possible meaning or use of it - or perhaps more?

Answer (score 2):

In "most definitely", the word "most" acts as an intensifier to "definitely", which itself means "without any doubt; certainly". It has only one possible meaning.

Answer (score 0):

It means Yes, for sure. I don't think it sounds stupid but then again I like to use profanity to intensify the meaning of words and feelings as well

Answer (score -2):

People MEAN it to be an intensifier, but it ends up making them sound stupid. Definite means without any doubt. If there is no chance of any doubt, how can there be an extra special amount of no doubt.

If people use their words correctly they don't need "intensifiers".